# Why do I have to use "closest" when there is only one element with the specified class name?

Tags: jquery

While studying with codeschool, this variable assignment is considered right.

```
var dailyPrice = +$(this).closest(".tour").data("daily-price");
```

While my original answer was considered wrong.

```
var dailyPrice = +$('.tour').data('daily-price');
```

And here is the complete html, which only has one "tour" class. There's no ambiguity about it. So why was my answer wrong?

```
<div class="tour" data-daily-price="357">
  <h2>Paris, France Tour</h2>
  <p>$<span id="total">2,499</span> for <span id="nights-count">7</span> Nights</p>
  <p>
    <label for="nights">Number of Nights</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="nights" value="7" type="number">
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is useful if there are multiple instances of `tour` elements inside the page, then when a particular `input` elements value is changed we need to find out the daily price for the corresponding tour. In that case if you use `$('.tour')` it will always give the price of the very first tour instead of the one whose input value is changed. In that case we need to find out the `tour` element which is the ancestor of the element in question that is the reason for using `.closest()`.

If you are sure that there will never be more than one `tour` element in the page then there is no need to use `.closest()`

Comment: OK. Codeschool was just forcing me to use .closest() for educational purposes.

Comment: It isn't that there was any "error," likely they were trying to make the point that `$('.tour')` can select many elements and when trying to use `data` will only operate on the first, while `.closest` will only get one (the one you are interested in) so you operate on the correct one.